# loop through an array and check if array inside it has a certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, foreach

I have an array of objects like below

```
const arr = 
  [ { a: '', b: '', arr: [ { label: '2' }, { label: '3' }                 ] } 
  , { a: '', b: '', arr: [ { label: '1' }, { label: '2' }, { label: '3' } ] } 
  , { a: '', b: '', arr: [ { label: '1' }, { label: '3' }                 ] } 
  ]
```

I need to filter this array and get the objects in which the arr array has the label value of 2.

ie., expected result :

```
const arr = 
  [ { a: '', b: '', arr: [ { label: '2' }, { label: '3' }                 ] } 
  , { a: '', b: '', arr: [ { label: '1' }, { label: '2' }, { label: '3' } ] } 
  ]
```

I have tried something like this:

```
array.forEach((item) => item.arr.filter(i) => i.label === '2')
```

how would we get back a filtered array looping through this array which has label values as "2" inside the arr array?

How can I achieve the expected result?

Comment: `const result = arr.filter( ({ arr }) => arr.some( ({label}) => label === '2' ));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `filter`, `some` and `destructuring`

```js
const arr = 
  [ { a: '', b: '', arr: [ { label: '2' }, { label: '3' }                 ] } 
  , { a: '', b: '', arr: [ { label: '1' }, { label: '2' }, { label: '3' } ] } 
  , { a: '', b: '', arr: [ { label: '1' }, { label: '3' }                 ] } 
  ]
  
const output = arr.filter(({ arr }) => arr.some(({ label }) => label === '2'));
  
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```js
let oldArray = array = [
   {
      "a":"",
      "b":"",
      "arr":[
         {
            "label":"2"
         },
         {
            "label":"3"
         }
      ]
   },
{
      "a":"",
      "b":"",
      "arr":[
         {
            "label":"1"
         },
         {
            "label":"2"
         },
         {
            "label":"3"
         }
      ]
   },
{
      "a":"",
      "b":"",
      "arr":[
         {
            "label":"1"
         },
         {
            "label":"3"
         }
      ]
   }
]

let newArray = oldArray.filter(item=>
  item.arr && item.arr.filter(inner=> inner.label == "2").length >= 1
)

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method along with [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [
  { a: '', b: '', arr: [ { label: '2' }, { label: '3' }] },
  { a: '', b: '', arr: [ { label: '1' }, { label: '2' }, { label: '3' } ] },
  { a: '', b: '', arr: [ { label: '1' }, { label: '3' }] } 
];

const filteredArr = arr.filter(({ arr }) => arr.some(o => o.label === '2'));

console.log(filteredArr);
```